# Need to create a UI5 custom control which need some other AMD modules

Tags: javascript, custom-controls, sapui5, arcgis-js-api

I need to create a UI5 coustom control where i need to load the ESRI Map.

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/Control"
], function (Control) {
"use strict";
return Control.extend("custom.map.ESRIMap", {
    init : function(){
        this._map = new Map('mapDiv',esriMapOptions);
    }
});
});
```

This is how i want to write my custom control.

Where i have loaded ESRI javascript API as

```
jQuery.sap.includeScript({
                     url : "https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/init.js",
                     id : 'esriApi' 
                 });
```

Problem i am facing is ESRI library loading,  if i load as below,

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/Control"
    "esri/map
    ], function (Control,Map) {
```

It will not load because its not ui5 Module

i have to do require as below

```
require(["esri/map"],function(Map){
```

i need help to write a UI5 Custom control or Module where i have to load UI5 module and ESRI AMD module together before return i the first code.

Comment: which IDE/Editor your are using? I had same issue so need some more details.  are you using any other JS library except jquery?

Comment: IDE eclipse, only ui5

Comment: If i am not wrong you are developing something like this https://github.com/Vikash2402/Lumira-Custom-Extension-AboutLumira   instead of Visualization extension you are using SAPUI5 Application.. correct?

Comment: ohk eclipse.. let me check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, most AMD module loaders don't support the Dojo AMD plugin syntax (ex: [dojo/i18n](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/i18n.html)) used by the ArcGIS API for JavaScript. Therefore the only reliable way to load those modules is to use Dojo's `require()` as you mention above.

When using other module loaders, we often use the "nested require" patterns. In your case it would look something like this:

```
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/Control"
], function (Control) {
    "use strict";
    return Control.extend("custom.map.ESRIMap", {
      init : function() {
        require(["esri/map"],function(Map){
          // now you have access to Control and Map
          this._map = new Map('mapDiv',esriMapOptions);
        });
      }
    });
});
```

Keep in mind that `require()` is async and in all likelihood going to result in network requests to fetch module scripts. I know nothing about the UI5 framework and whether or not it's OK to make such async requests in a control's `init()`. If not, you may need to find another place for the require.

This pattern is described in more detail [in this blog post](http://tomwayson.com/2016/11/27/using-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript-in-applications-built-with-webpack/) which links out to other examples of how it is used in React and Angular applications. You may be able to use the [esri-loader](https://github.com/tomwayson/esri-loader) as well, which just provides an API to hide the use of the `require()` global.